# .forceignore isn't detecting the files

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, .forceignore

After playing a bit with Salesforce DX, pushing and pulling stuff, I decided to try out the `.forceignore` file, but I can't seem to make it work.

At the moment I have the following structure:

[image: file directory]

[image: Project structure]

and my `.forceignore` file contains the following lines:

```
force-app/main/default/apex-module1/TestingForceIgnore.cls
force-app/main/default/apex-module1/TestingForceIgnore.cls-meta.xml
```

Nonetheless, everytime I modify the files and I push the source, they get pushed. To a point, I thought about deleting them from the scratch org and re-creating them, but still.

Have I written the paths correctly? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: This `.forceignore` file is located at `force-app/.forceignore`, it looks like?

Comment: @sfdcfox no, it's in the root directory as it should. I added another image for more clarity.

Comment: @sfdcfox I'm still googling and I found this: `Add the file to the Metadata retrieve directory (with package.xml) for force:mdapi:convert.`. I haven't done this nor I know what it means. Could this be the issue?

Comment: I linked that in my (now deleted) answer. The primary purpose of `force:mdapi:convert` is to use an older Force.com IDE project to convert it to the newer folder design that DX uses. This doesn't apply to you if you're not using `force:mdapi:convert`.

Comment: Might just be a font issue, but when I look at your screenshots the file name looks like it has a space after the period. E.g. `. forceignore`.

Comment: @DanielBallinger LOL. True, it does look like it. Ima try it later at home and give you guys feedback. Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to answer this question!

Just like @DanielBallinger said in the comments below the answer, **there was a space between the period and the *forceignore***... so obviously it wasn't working (duh!).